# Solution for an inequality

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, inequality

I want to solve this inequality for $z$
$$(z+1) \left(1-e^x\right)-e^y\geq 0$$ 
where $-\infty <x\leq \log \left(\frac{1}{z+1}\right)$ and $-\infty <y\leq 0$.

I am struggling because $z$ appears in the domain of $x$, i.e., $-\infty <x\leq \log \left(\frac{1}{z+1}\right)$.

Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Not a full solution, but you should be able to take it up from where I leave it.
$$
(z+1) \left(1-e^x\right)-e^y\geq 0\Rightarrow (z+1) \left(1-e^x\right)\geq e^y\ .
$$
Now, you need to find out wheter $1-e^x$ is positive or negative (or zero), to be able to divide both sides of the inequality by $1-e^x$ (not flipping or flipping the inequality sign, respectively).

So, if $1-e^x>0\Rightarrow e^x<1\Rightarrow e^x<e^0\Rightarrow \boxed{x<0}$, then
$$
z+1\geq \frac{e^y}{1-e^x}\Rightarrow \boxed{z\geq \frac{e^y}{1-e^x}-1}\ .
$$
But we also know that
$$
x\leq\log\left(\frac{1}{z+1}\right)\Rightarrow x\leq -\log(z+1)\Rightarrow -x\geq \log(z+1)\Rightarrow e^{-x}\geq z+1\Rightarrow \boxed{z\leq e^{-x}-1}\ .
$$

So, for $x<0$ (and $y\leq 0$) we need to solve simultaneously the inequalities
$$
\begin{cases}
z \geq \frac{e^y}{1-e^x}-1\\
z\leq e^{-x}-1
\end{cases}\ .
$$
Now, we need to determine whether $\frac{e^y}{1-e^x}$ is larger or smaller than $e^{-x}$. This will give you cases on $x$ and $y$, to be analyzed separately.

Comment: I do not see any specific solution with this approach. For the first case, I may get $z\geq\infty$ when $x\to 0, y\to -\infty$, and for the second case, I may get $z\leq-1$ when $x\to \infty$.